# Show Google Analytics data with automatic authorization in website?

Tags: jquery, curl, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have this js to render charts from Google Analytics data below using the  [ga-ez-dash library](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html#copypaste) to show user visits history, browser history etc.
                                        I am able to render charts but the problem is that I dont want all of my clients to login with our Google Analytics Account.Is there any way to make the login automatic through a jquery post/curl php etc or can i make the Google Analytics data public.Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this.Any help would be greatly appreciated guys!

```
var API_KEY = 'Enter Your API Key Here';
    var CLIENT_ID = 'Enter Your Client ID Here';
    var TABLE_ID = 'Enter your Table ID here';
    // Format of table ID is ga:xxx where xxx is the profile ID.

gadash.configKeys({
  'apiKey': API_KEY,
  'clientId': CLIENT_ID
});

// Create a new Chart that queries visitors for the last 30 days and plots
// visualizes in a line chart.
var chart1 = new gadash.Chart({
  'type': 'LineChart',
  'divContainer': 'line-chart-example',
  'last-n-days':30,
  'query': {
    'ids': TABLE_ID,
    'metrics': 'ga:visitors',
    'dimensions': 'ga:date'
  },
  'chartOptions': {
    height:600,
    title: 'Visits in January 2011',
    hAxis: {title:'Date'},
    vAxis: {title:'Visits'},
    curveType: 'function'
  }
}).render();
```

Comment: If the same data is being accessed multiple times then store/cache it locally. It's fairly easy to just serialise the dict that the API returns and chuck it into some local storage.

Comment: For the API to return data, the user must be authenticated and thats is what the problem is, can i autologin the user and make the google analytics data public ??!

Comment: There is no official way to automatically login and pull data, and there is no way to make it "public".

Comment: Is it ? What other way could i use to login the user to Google Analytics Account with our credentials ?  I have also tried using the [gapi](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) class.I can retrieve the data but somehow its not as good as the above library :(

Comment: Try [Google Apps script](https://script.google.com) the output of which you can then embed into a page. They provide a GA connector.

Comment: That was a good idea, but does the Web app done through Apps Script require login for access?

Comment: One of the deployment options allows anonymous user access.

Answer (score 1):

You can [log into Google services with an OAuth2 token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2); just get the user to log in once to their Google account, approve your access and store the token. Then you can log into the portion of their account you have access to automatically.

P.S. To do it in Javascript, they provide a [client API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication). All client APIs listed at the bottom of the first page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that services like the ez-dash library use client side oauth to authenticate.  In order to use a fixed username / password, you will need to set up a "Service Account" on the Google API Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/) to allow server-to-server communication.

If you're looking for a solution that's open source which will let you display Google Analytics data in Charts on your website then you can take a look at my new project (though this is .NET based, not PHP based) https://code.google.com/p/google-analytics-charts-aspnet/, or download the nuGet package here https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalytics.GoogleCharts.NET/.

For a PHP solution I did find this though I haven't used it https://github.com/mikhailkozlov/Show-Analytics-Data-With-Google-Chart-Tools.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  *(disclaimer - I work with them)*

This is a service we developed so developers such as yourself don't need to get acquainted with the API.  All you do is create a chart on our site, grab a snippet of code, and embed on your site where you want the chart to show.  We support all different chart types, and the charts themselves are capable of dynamic queries (i.e. if you want the chart to show last 7 days,30 days,year, etc).